# method activate of object _worksheet failed

Tags: excel-2010, vba7, excellibrary

I want to display a specific sheet when I open the Excel file, but I am facing an error, please guide me to fix this error.

`Private Sub Workbook_Open()` 
`Worksheets("rahnama").Activate` 
`End Sub` 
[image]